# SQL Query not returning entity in SELECT *, but returns entity when specifying ID

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am writing a simple Spring Boot RESTful API with two requests:

`/getEmployee`

`/getEmpoyee/{id}`

I have two queries pulling data from a SQL DB, one for each request. The queries look as followed:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE';
```

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND EMPLOYEE_ID = ?;
```

When I call the requests, I get the expected value from `getEmployee/12345`, but when pulling all employees with `getEmployee`, this employee is not on the payload.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Java Code:

```
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE'";
String query2 = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND EMPLOYEE_ID = ?";

List<Employee> employees= jdbcTemplate.query(query1, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Employee.class));

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee=(Employee) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query2, new Object[] { id },
                    new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Employee.class));
```

Comment: I'm guessing the employee is there but you are only looking at the first few records so you don't see the employee.  You probably just have to scroll through the result set.

Comment: I ran the SQL queries on SQL Developer, and search for Employee and it's not there when executing the first query

Comment: . . Maybe it is bringing back the rows in groups of 1,000 or something like that.

Comment: DB is not that big, it has 100 employees

Comment: Does select * from employee return results?

Comment: yes, but out of the 100 it returns 86

Comment: Does that include employee 12345?

Comment: Let's show your Java source code!

Comment: If you're seeing some results but some are missing then I'd guess you're either fetching too many times (skipping over rows) or not enough times (stopping before you get to this ID). Without your code we can't really tell. It doesn't really seem to be anything to do with Oracle though.

Comment: I edited post include java code